# Implementing web socket server as web role in Azure cloud service

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, websocket

I have a MVC4 website which requires a web socket server which I have implemented using [Alchemy](http://alchemywebsockets.net/) in the web role of my Azure cloud service like so:

```
namespace MvcWebRole1
{
    public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        private static List<UserContext> Users = new List<UserContext>();

        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(OnStartWebSocketServer, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            return base.OnStart();
        }

        private void OnStartWebSocketServer()
        {
            var aServer = new WebSocketServer(5004, IPAddress.Any)
            {
                OnReceive = OnReceive,
                OnSend = OnSend,
                OnConnect = OnConnect,
                OnConnected = OnConnected,
                OnDisconnect = OnDisconnect,
                TimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
            };
            aServer.Start();           
        }
```

I am currently still trying to debug locally, and am not able to connect to the server, I get `Unexpected response code: 200` in the Chrome debugger.

Is there any way that I can check that the server is even running e.g. displaying the console? Is this even a good approach? I am completely new to Azure and web sockets and am still trying to learn the basics, so please excuse me if I haven't checked some basic settings.

EDIT: 
As suggested by Sandrino I have checked the web role end points. I have switched everything to port 5004 in the hopes that it is unused. However I still get `Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Remapping private port 5004 to 5005 in role 'MvcWebRole1' to avoid conflict during emulation.`. I also added an exception to my firewall for these ports but still nothing works.

Comment: Have you added an Input Endpoint for port 81 to your Web Role?

Comment: I did that now but still the same error. In the output I get 'Remapping private port 81 to 82 in role 'MvcWebRole1' to avoid conflict during emulation.' So I changed the port in my client but still the same error :/

Comment: @SandrinoDiMattia I figured it out thanks to your comment, if you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. The endpoints that I was opening were HTTP whereas web sockets work over TCP. In order to solve the problem there must be:

- One endpoint for the website using http.
- Another endpoint for the web socket server using tcp and the port specified in webrole.cs